# Is there a way I can publish an exe file to be in the same directory as an azure web job?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a web job that uses an exe that is best called when it is sitting in a directory and can be located. The problem is that I don't know how to get this exe to be published with the web job. I tried using a resources folder in the webjob project and copying them to output directory but that didn't upload them and so the only other option I can think of is uploading the files to a non temporary directory on the web site but that is leaking the encapsulation of the web job.

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you expecting windows azure to run the .exe?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331425/Running-an-EXE-in-a-WebRole-on-Windows-Azure

Comment: If I understood correctly, your problem is that storing the exe in the same folder as the webjob will "confuse" Azure, and it will erroneously call that exe instead of your webjob. If that's the case, just rename your exe to another extension

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm not having a problem with it being confused I'm having a problem with actually getting the exe there in a directory with the web job where I can access it and use it. I'm not trying to run the exe as a webjob but my webjob does use it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use visual studio to publish a webjob, it publishes all its dependencies as well. ie VS pushes all the dependencies available under the bin folder. So, add a reference to the dependent project and VS will take care of publishing this dependency as well.

Comment: I'm not having trouble publishing the webjob. The webjob is published and started just fine. The problem is that there is an exe the webjob uses that I have in a folder in the webjob's project which isn't published with the webjob. I want to know if I can get this exe to publish with the webjob to a place where it can be used.

Comment: Right click the webjob project, add reference to the webjobhelper project. Publish the webjob project and VS publish will take care of publishing both the webjob and the webjobhelper.